# BufferedInputStream won't work after KeyStore.load()

Tags: java, security, classloader, bufferedinputstream

My JavaWS application will run in an intern network and so it is signed with the company's own certificate and also the SSL certificate is from the company's root CA. So because of the huge amount of computers its unlikely to import the certificates on each comupter manually. So I extended my app with a class which should automatically import the certificates, this works from the console and the IDE but not if the application is executed by java web start :(

Code

```
        cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");

        signCertIn = ClassLoader.class.getResourceAsStream((pack + signCertName + ".cer"));
        sslCertIn = ClassLoader.class.getResourceAsStream((pack + sslCertName) + ".crt");

        File file = new File(new File(System.getProperty("java.home") + SEP + "lib" + SEP + "security"), "cacerts");
        javaCertIn = new FileInputStream(file);

        KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        keystore.load(javaCertIn, passphrase);

        javaCertIn.close();

        if (!keystore.containsAlias(signCertName)) {
            bis = new BufferedInputStream(signCertIn); // <<<<<<< Exception thrown here
            while (bis.available() > 0) {
                Certificate cert = cf.generateCertificate(bis);
                keystore.setCertificateEntry(signCertName, cert);
            }
            save = true;
            signCertIn.close();
        }

        if (!keystore.containsAlias(sslCertName)) {
            bis = new BufferedInputStream(sslCertIn);
            while (bis.available() > 0) {
                Certificate cert = cf.generateCertificate(bis);
                keystore.setCertificateEntry(sslCertName, cert);
            }
            save = true;
            sslCertIn.close();
        }

        if (save) {
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            keystore.store(out, passphrase);
            out.close();
        }
```

JavaWS console output

```
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.getInIfOpen(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.available(Unknown Source)
at at.sviss.util.cert.Certificates.install(Certificates.java:48)
at at.sviss.Main.main(Main.java:91)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.executeApplication(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.executeMainClass(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.doLaunchApp(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: You need full permissions to access the file system.  Does your program have that?  Even so, I do not think java webstart use certificates in the same way as stand alone programs.

Comment: Before launch the .jar file itselfe is verified with the default "cacerts" keystore file from the install directory. And YES, my application has all-permissions, defined in the jnlp!

Comment: Don't use available() as a test for end of stream. That's not what it's for. See the Javadoc.

Comment: Permissions is a very frequent Java WebStart problem.  If you know this, you will save people time in mentally reproducing your problems which is part of asking a good question in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the ClassLoader:

```
signCertIn = ClassLoader.class.getResourceAsStream((pack + signCertName + ".cer"));
```

Use the class itselfe:

```
signCertIn = Certificates.class.getResourceAsStream((pack + signCertName + ".cer"));
```

Worked for me ...

Comment: `Class.getResourceAsStream` returns `null` if the resource is not found. Poor design IMO. `ClassLoader.class`, being a bootstrap class, will have the call bizarrely forwarded to `ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream`. That is to resource on classpath (or extension classes or boot classpath). That made more sense prior to Java 2.

Answer (score 0):

Keystore.load() will read the input stream to end of stream. It doesn't make sense to try to read anything else from it afterwards. Try reopening the stream, for whatever purpose you're doing that. Not that it makes sense. If keystore.load() didn't load your certificates I don't know why you think your own code will do any better.

Comment: I only call 'keystore.load()' once so the InputStream javaCertIn is read to end and closed afterwards. So I dont see any problems here? I just used the wrong class I think?